# Scala: How do I programmatically create an XML tag and insert a value in it?

Tags: xml, scala

I currently have something like this:

```
val green = "GREEN"
```

I want to programmatically create a tag and insert `green` as its only child. it should look like this:

```
val blue = if(blah) "INDIGO" else "SKY"
val fooElem:Elem = <{blue}> green<{blue}>
```

obviously, this does not work. I then find out that an empty `Elem` can be generated like this:

```
val fooEmpty = new Elem(null, blue, scala.xml.Null , scala.xml.TopScope, false) //this is <INDIGO></INDIGO> or <SKY></SKY>
```

Now, I do not know how to programmatically add `green` as its child/value so that it becomes `fooElem`. How can I do this?

Comment: string interpolation is an alternative (less safe of course). You can also create an [`Elem`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/xml/scala/xml/Elem$.html) directly without DSL. If you need "child"s - they're last parameter of its constructor

Comment: just add the text as a `child` parameter of your `Elem`: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/xml/index.html#scala.xml.Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like that:

```
val fooEmpty = new Elem(null, blue, scala.xml.Null , scala.xml.TopScope, false, Text(green))
```

The constructor is:

```
new
Elem(prefix: String, label: String, attributes1: MetaData, scope: NamespaceBinding, minimizeEmpty: Boolean, child: Node*)
```

so you can pass the child nodes as the last argument